# psutil not displaying correct CPU usage

Tags: python, cpu-usage, psutil

Here is my code:

```
import psutil
import time


while True:
    cpu_usage = psutil.cpu_percent()
    ram_usage = psutil.virtual_memory().percent
    # gpu_usage = psutil.gpu_percent()

    print("CPU Usage: ", cpu_usage,"RAM Usage: ", ram_usage)
    time.sleep(2)
    #print("RAM Usage:", ram_usage)
```

The problem is when I run the code CPU usage displayed from the code is not equal to task manager.

[image: low-contrast screen shot]

Comment: How exactly do you conclude that the results are incorrect? Your low-contrast screen shot seems to be truncated so we can't see the scale on the graph (if there is one).